# porting virtual video driver in linux kernel

Tags: linux-device-driver, v4l2

I am trying to build vivi driver in linux kernel..
I tried using make menuconfig but i didnt see any option to enable vivi driver.
Can someone tell me the process to enable vivi drivers in kernel

-kiran

Answer (score 1):

LINUX KERNEL 3.12 :

The support for vivi [virtual video driver] can be enable by following:

---

Device Driver --> 
Multimedia support --> 
Cameras/video grabbers support --> 
Media test drivers --> 
Virtual Video Driver.

Answer (score 0):

It's under 'Device Drivers' -> 'Multimedia support' -> 'Video capture adapters' -> 'Virtual Video Driver'.

It has dependencies on VIDEO_DEV, VIDEO_V4L2 and ( FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE or STI_CONSOLE ).
It's also not supported on Sparc machines.

Reading the Kconfig files is usually the best place to start looking for this kind of thing.